# c# linq create dynamic query with

Tags: c#, linq

I have 5 Dropdown lists which are filled with the columns of my dataset.
That works well.

```
var query = ds.Tables["Input"].AsEnumerable().Select
(a => new
{ID = a.Field<string>("ID"),
Element1 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement1.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element2 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement2.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element3 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement3.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element4 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement4.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element5 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement5.SelectedItem.ToString())});
```

But that only works if all ComboBoxes are not empty.
How can I build the query with only 2 selected Boxes dynamically?
I tried it with a `StingBuilder` and `if (comboBoxName.SelectedIndex >= 0)` statements, but I'm wondering if there is another method to do that within LINQ.

Comment: It is difficult because the comboboxes are assigned to discrete variables. So in order to choose from them you will have to refer to them individually which makes it unlikely that you can simplify this with LINQ.

Comment: I do not know if this lives on or not, and smells like sql and vb has a baby, but maybe it could work in your context? https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: I am not getting what you want to achieve.... Do you need a condition to deal with empty comboboxes? If so, try to extract the logic for creating the record to a new method, and then extract a nuplCheck method, it will look and feel much cleaner. You could of course have at least a class between the comboboxes to interpret combobox to human language and perhaps the database. Just a thought :)

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but as oliver wrote, LINQ wasn't the right tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy solution.

Create a List from the (not empty) ComboBoxes:

```
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

  if (comboBoxElement1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
  {
    myCollection.Add(comboBoxElement1.SelectedItem.ToString());
  }
  if (comboBoxElement2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
  {
    myCollection.Add(comboBoxElement2.SelectedItem.ToString());
  }
```

Create a DataView from the InputTable:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtInput);
```

Write to the selected DataColumns from comboBoxes to the ouputTable:

```
dtOutput = dv.ToTable(true, myCollection.ToArray());
```

---

You can refactor the above by creating a method such as:

```
public AddSelected(IList list, params ComboBox[] comboBoxes)
{
    foreach (var comboBox in comboBoxes)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            list.Add(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then calling with code such as:

```
AddSelected(myCollection, comboBoxElement1, comboBoxElement2 /* , ... */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a where clause asking for only selectedIndex != 0

like this (in a WinForm):

```
result = Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(cb => cb.SelectedIndex != -1).Aggregate(result, (current, cb) => current + (cb.SelectedItem + ","));
```

Have you try this:

```
    var query = ds.Tables["Input"].AsEnumerable().Where(cb => cb.SelectedIndex != -1).Select
(a => new
{ID = a.Field<string>("ID"),
Element1 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement1.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element2 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement2.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element3 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement3.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element4 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement4.SelectedItem.ToString()),
Element5 = a.Field<string>(comboBoxElement5.SelectedItem.ToString())});
```